# Where to set/keep Kadira Debug Authentication Key(Incorrect Debug Auth Key, Try again!)?

Tags: debugging, meteor, kadira

My first question is where to set/keep KADIRA_DEBUG_AUTH_KEY=”XXXXXXXXX" authentication key(Right now I have kept it in app/server/kadira.js). And second question is the authentication key is user defined OR app secrete key which we can get by creating app.Tried self  defined key but it is showing as "Incorrect Debug Auth Key, Try again!".

```
  My app/server/kadira.js looks like below:


  Meteor.startup(function() {
    Kadira.connect('xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx');
    KADIRA_DEBUG_AUTH_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxx";
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Where to keep sensitive app data - [Meteor settings](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-settings). They have option to have private (accessible only on server) and public settings, that will be accessible on client
2. Yes, secret key is obtainable, not random.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I will work on it.

Comment: @Rashmi if it helps, then mark the answer as correct and close the question ;)